# Using same :as for two rails routes, with GET and POST for different actions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-routing, ruby-on-rails-5

I've stumbled into this problem, where I'm trying to route my login paths, and I'm trying to achieve `GET /login` sends to `sessions#new` and `POST /login` sends to `sessions#create`. Although, Rails doesn't seem to recognize this as not a

```
get "/login" => "sessions#new", :as => :login
post "/login" => "sessions#create", :as => :login
```

This raises the following error on boot:

`` lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:507:in 'add_route': Invalid route name, already in use: 'login'  (ArgumentError)
You may have defined two routes with the same name using the `:as` option, or you may be overriding a route already defined by a resource with the same naming. For the latter, you can restrict the routes created with `resources` as explained here: 
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#restricting-the-routes-created ``

Would the best practice be to do a `resources :sessions, only: [:new, :create], as: :login` although I'd get URL Helpers like `login_index_path` and `new_login_path` and not just `login_path` as originally intended?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what I did on my Rails app.

```
get    'login'   => 'sessions#new'
post   'login'   => 'sessions#create'
```

I think the `:as => :login` part is what is causing your error, I think of that as assigning an alias, and you can't use the same alias for two different routes.

Comment: That's true.. Gives the exact same result - I have no clue why I didn't think of this! Thanks!

Comment: but it isn't two separate routes, its the same route and two methods. Rails `resources` does this all the time with, for example, `POST /users` mapping to `users#create` and `GET /users` mapping to `users#index`

Answer (score 2):

You can pass a block to `scope`:

```rb
scope as: 'login' do
  get "/login" => "sessions#new"
  post "/login" => "sessions#create"
end
```

This also works for routes with params, for example:

```rb
scope as: 'post' do
  patch  '/posts/:id' => 'posts#update'
  put    '/posts/:id' => 'posts#update'
  delete '/posts/:id' => 'posts#destroy'
end
```

which results in:

```sh
$ rails routes -c post
Prefix Verb   URI Pattern            Controller#Action
post PATCH    /posts/:id(.:format)   posts#update
     PUT      /posts/:id(.:format)   posts#update
     DELETE   /posts/:id(.:format)   posts#destroy
```